# When is the union of a family of subspaces of a vector space also a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is not difficult to prove that the union of a chain (or, more generally, a directed family) of subspaces of a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$.

Given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that the union of $\mathcal{F}$ is a subspace of $V$, is it true that $\mathcal{F}$ is a directed family?

If not, is there a "nice" characterization of families of subspaces whose union is a subspace?

Comment: The union of two subspaces is a subspace if and only if one of the subspaces is contained in the other.

Comment: Is it a finite family?

Comment: For a vector space over an infinite field, it is never the case that a finite family unions to a subspace, unless one of the family's elements contains all the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The family $\mathcal{F}$ of one-dimensional subspaces of $V$ has the property that its union is the whole space, but it is not directed. Note that if $V$ is finite-dimensional over a finite field, then $\mathcal{F}$ is finite as well. I don't know of any characterisation though.